# In iOS, is the UITableViewDataSource considered the program's logic?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm following a UITableView tutorial and I've learned that the UITableView is a view object which doesn't handle the logic or data, it primarily the view or user interface.  As I continued reading it says that the UITableView requires a "datasource".  My question is this, is the datasource the program's logic?

Answer (score 1):

IOS app development widely use `Delegate` design pattern. Almost all UIView have their own `Delegate` `Protocol`. Before understand `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` `Protocol` try to learn about `Delegate` design pattern.
If you work with UITableView you have to implement atleast 2 protocol in your ViewController.
1. [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) : The delegate of a UITableView object must adopt the UITableViewDelegate protocol. Optional methods of the protocol allow the delegate to manage selections, configure section headings and footers, help to delete and reorder cells, and perform other actions.
2. [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource): The UITableViewDataSource protocol is adopted by an object that mediates the application’s data model for a UITableView object. The data source provides the table-view object with the information it needs to construct and modify a table view.